# HTML5 canvas tracking grid with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I'm having an issue with a HTML5 canvas idea. It's basically a game, whereby the player is always centered in the canvas - this means that for 'movement' the rest of the scene must move instead. I have this setup, but I also wanted to have a clickable grid (50x50 px) on top of the scene (as if the game's elements are made up of blocks).

For drawing the mouse box I have the following code:

```
// Draw mouse box
if(game.mouse.o){
    var mouseBlockX = (Math.floor(game.mouse.x / 50) * 50) + (game.view.x % 50);
    // Previous attempt:
    // var mouseBlockX = (Math.floor((game.mouse.x - ( 0.5 * game.view.x % 50)) / 50) * 50) + (game.view.x % 50);
    var mouseBlockY = (Math.floor((game.mouse.y - ( 0.5 * game.view.y % 50)) / 50) * 50) + (game.view.y % 50);

    ctx.fillText('Block: ' + mouseBlockX.toString() + '/' + mouseBlockY.toString(), 5, 400);
    ctx.fillText(Math.abs(game.view.x) % 50, 5, 410);

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#DDDDFF';
    ctx.strokeWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeRect(mouseBlockX, mouseBlockY, 50, 50);
}
```

Essentially, my main issue here is that the following line doesn't work properly:

```
(Math.floor((game.mouse.x - ( 0.5 * game.view.x % 50)) / 50) * 50) + (game.view.x % 50)
```

...and I've tried to find a correct version, but it's beating me at the minute. What would be the correct formula so that the mouse's box follows the mouse, but also compensates for the view moving? Have I made it too complicated so I'm missing the answer?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/y14ftv0o/

**UPDATE:** changed variables to be clearer. To try and explain in a better way: when the view moves, the 'grid' doesn't properly stick to its original position. When the view moves, the grid should look like it is fixed to the original objects on the scene (essentially so the user thinks they're 'clicking' on things in the scene on a grid).

Comment: "An explanation of the various variables" - Just a tip, give your variables names that don't require a separate explanation.

Comment: @Jonathan It was just shorthand for myself, so that my code isn't all over the place with myGame.thisVariable.thisIsAnotherVariable etc... :)

Comment: No need to defend the choice to me. Defend it to yourself when you write additional code in a few months.

Comment: @Jonathan This is just a proof of concept. Simply put, I had an idea and wanted to test it, but I got stuck. If I was writing this properly, I wouldn't write it shorthand.